# Learn this decision problem

Tags: probability, machine-learning, decision-theory

**Problem statement:** Here's a single-player probabilistic game. In front of you are $L$ urns, each containing bills of various values. You get $N$ chances to draw a bill from any urn you like, check its value, then put it back. You may draw from the same urn multiple times. On the $(N+1)$th draw, you get to keep the bill as your winnings from the game. How can you maximize your expected winnings?

If it makes it easier, you can assume $N > L$.

This might be too difficult to solve without making certain assumptions about the distributions of bills in each urn. A perfectly general solution wouldn't assume anything about bill denominations or the number of bills in each urn, but I'd still appreciate a less general solution.

**My thoughts so far:** there is probably something in the reinforcement learning literature related to this, but I haven't quite found it. The explore-exploit tradeoff is present in a weird form here. You lose nothing getting bad draws in the first $N$ rounds, so from one point of view, you should be fully focused on exploring. On the other hand, you still should explore promising urns more thoroughly. Maximizing information gain won't be the best strategy, because you care less about further information from the urns that already seem to have generally lower bill values.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Can we redraw from the same urn?  If we draw twice from the same urn, are we assured of getting the same value?  Or are you perhaps trying to state a variant of the classical [Secretary Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem)?  For that one, though, it is usually given that you can never go back to a rejected sample and that, while you can always compare $A$ to $B$ (and we never get equality), we have no sense of scale (so you can't say, e.g., "$A$ is a billion times better than $B$", only that $A>B$.)

Comment: @lulu Edited question. You can draw from the same urn as many times as you like, and the point is that each urn contains many bills, so you will most likely not see the same value on your second draw.

Comment: @FrankSeidl do the bins contain the same amount of bills? Either way, do you know a priori how many bills are in each bin?

Comment: @E-A I'll edit again in a second. I'd prefer you didn't, but I'd still be curious to see a solution that uses that knowledge

Comment: Estimating how many bills are in each bin feels similar to (but not the same as) estimating the size of populations in nature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture

Comment: @TomKern I agree that there is a similarity; both problems involve making inferences about a distribution from samples. But my problem is (in my opinion) harder, because you also have to make decisions about which samples to take. That "experimental design" component is what makes it difficult.

Comment: I don't see how you can be sure to maximize the winnings unless each urn contains only one denomination. In this case you obviously go back to the urn on your (N+1) draw where you found the highest denomination on your previous N draws. If all urns have the same distributions and numbers of bills, you are back to zero each time you put the bill back. You can't get any information in this case at all. Unless I am missing something crucial here.

Comment: This is also similar, but not the same as the classical multi-armed bandit problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit